# Send Datetime from Android to Web Service .Net

Tags: android, .net, web-services, datetime, ksoap2

Why when i put this date in this format `2013-11-14 00:00:00` failure my android application 
and shows me this error:

```
java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500.
```

But when i put this format `2013-11-14` works correctly.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_FRES);   
            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            //adding parameters
            **request.addProperty("fechaConsultar", Fecha);**
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 30000);
```

Fecha is the string with the format of date.
My WebService retrieve a Datetime object.
This my web Service

```
    public List<FechaReservada> fechasReservadas(DateTime fechaConsultar)
    {
        return consultaFecha(fechaConsultar);

    }

    public List<FechaReservada> consultaFecha(DateTime fecha)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConexionMysql"].ConnectionString);
        List<FechaReservada> result = new List<FechaReservada>();
        FechaReservada fec;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("g_getSalonesbyFecha", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Fecha",fecha);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(ds);
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Rows)
            {
                fec = new FechaReservada();
                fec.Sucursal = int.Parse(dr["Sucursal"].ToString());
                fec.Salon = dr["Salon"].ToString();
                fec.Fecha = DateTime.Parse(dr["Fecha"].ToString());
                fec.Confirmada = dr["Confirmado"].ToString().Contains("1") ? true : false;
                result.Add(fec);
            }
            con.Close();
            return result;
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            con.Close();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: http status 500 means: 500 Server Error (HTTP/1.0 - RFC 1945) then i guess the problem with .net part, can you show how you are receiving the date?

Comment: If you are asking why you get failure when you submit one format rather than another, I would think it is as simple as the server is coded to parse the one format that works.

Comment: Based from my experience, .NET web service accepts ISO 8601 format for its `DateTime` type. Try using `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` (or `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`) for the format if you want to include the time.

Comment: Wow thanks antimo, the format that you said works correctly  thanks so much. 
And  thanks so much to everybody.

Comment: You do not want to be doing `fec.Fecha = DateTime.Parse(dr["Fecha"].ToString())`.  Instead do `fec.Fecha = (DateTime) dr["Fecha"]`.  Same for the other fields.